# Specify Revision weight for Azure Container Apps App during deployment

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-apps

right now i work on a pipeline to deploy our microservices to an azure-container-apps environment.

The deployment is done via azure-pipelines, since we use a TFS on prem i need to deploy new versions in a pipeline step with azure cli. For that i use the following command:

```
az containerapp update 
   --name my-service 
   --resource-group  rg-sample 
   --image sample.azurecr.io/my-service:8440 
   --min-replicas 1 
   --max-replicas 10
```

This works perfectly new revisions get published and receive all the traffic, and that is exactly the problem im facing.

I know i can activate revisions with the `az containerapp revision activate`, but the containerapp update command automatically activates the latest revision with a weight of 100%, at least that is what i can see when i review changes with the azure portal.

Im looking for a way to deploy new revisions with azure cli, but with the limitation that the latest revision which was at 100% percent traffic before the deployment, stays there until i say via azure cli switch over to that revision.

Has anyone an idea how to archive that?

Best Erik

Comment: I think you would need a separate command for that, like az containerapp ingress traffic, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/ingress/traffic?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-ingress-traffic-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is in multiple revision mode, you can:

```bash
# Make sure your app is in multiple revision mode 
$ az containerapp revision set-mode \
  --name $APP_NAME \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --mode multiple

# Get the current "latestRevision"
$ LATEST_REVISION=$(az containerapp show \
  --name $APP_NAME \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --query properties.latestRevisionName)

# Explicitly set 100% to the latestRevision by name
$ az containerapp ingress traffic set \
  --name $APP_NAME \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --revision-weight $LATEST_REVISION=100

> [
>   {
>     "latestRevision": true, # New revisions will get 0% by default
>     "weight": 0
>   },
>   {
>     "revisionName": "appname--84yjetr",
>     "weight": 100
>   }
> ]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, i will take a look tomorrow, but it looks promissing. Still not the easy way i hoped for, but who knows maybe i can twist it in a way it fits ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my sitation I have redeployed the existing revision with a new environment variable, where I'm updating the connection string that points to a copy of the database from another step. This step could be optional.

So, you'd do something like

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Update container to CopyDatabase'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      $latestRevision = az containerapp update --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroup }} --name ${{ parameters.containerApp }} --set-env-vars CONNECTIONSTRINGS__MYDB="Server=tcp:${{ parameters.solution }}-sqlsrv-${{ parameters.environment }}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=${{ parameters.solution }}-copy-sqldb-${{ parameters.environment }};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication='Active Directory Default';" --query properties.latestRevisionName -o tsv
      az containerapp ingress traffic set --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroup }} --name ${{ parameters.containerApp }} --revision-weight "${latestRevision}=100"
```

That `--query properties.latestRevisionName -o tsv` gets the name from the freshly updated container app. This revision name will be receiving all the traffic.

The **most important take away here** is that you are 100% sure that this is the revision you just have updated. In theory you could end up in a situation where there are two deployments running simultaneously!

Next, you'll deploy the new image

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Create container revision
  name: deployImage
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    inlineScript: |
      $latestRevision = az containerapp update --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroup }} --name ${{  parameters.containerApp }} --image ${{ parameters.acrServer }}/images/${{ parameters.solution }}/$(imageName):$(Build.BuildId) --set-env-vars CONNECTIONSTRINGS__MYDB="Server=tcp:${{ parameters.solution }}-sqlsrv-${{ parameters.environment }}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=${{ parameters.solution }}-sqldb-${{ parameters.environment }};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication='Active Directory Default';" --query properties.latestRevisionName -o tsv
      az containerapp revision label add --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroup }} --name ${{  parameters.containerApp }} --label staging --revision latest

      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=newRevision;isOutput=true]$latestRevision"
```

So here, once again, we get the revision name.

Besides getting the revision name we also add a label to the new container image, so the URL will be predicatable, so you'd be able to test it (e.g. exposed via frontdoor).

The revision name will be set in a variable with `isOutput=true` so we can use it in another job.

Then, with these next jobs you'd be able to test the staging and after reviewing you could complete the pipeline:

```yaml
- job: CheckStaging
  dependsOn:
    - Deploy
  pool: server
  steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      displayName: 'Check the staging'

- job: ActivateNewVersion
  dependsOn:
    - CheckStaging
    - Deploy
  variables:
    latestRevision: $[ dependencies.Deploy.outputs['deployImage.newRevision'] ]
  steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
        scriptType: pscore
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          Write-Host "Set traffic to revision $(latestRevision)"
          az containerapp ingress traffic set --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroup }} --name ${{ parameters.containerApp }} --revision-weight "$(latestRevision)=100"
          az containerapp revision label remove --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroup }} --name ${{ parameters.containerApp }} --label staging
```

This last step sets the load to 100% and removes the label.